Pharmacokinetics and Calculus
I found this article from Northwestern University regarding using calculus in medicine. The article summarizes how the differential equation for the rate of change in the concentration of a drug in the bloodstream can be formulated by subtracting the rate of absorption from the rate of elimination. I wonder how the author obtained the differential equation using the approach mentioned above. Like where does the ka/(ka-ke) come from?
enter image description here
You can have a look at the article (linked below) fa or better understanding of the context.
https://sites.northwestern.edu/recalculated/2019/05/05/calculus-in-medicine/

The factor of $\frac{k_a}{k_a - k_e}$ comes from the definition of what the two constants $k_a$ and $k_e$ actually represent. Unfortunately, the article did not see fit to provide that information., just calling them "constants".  Presumably the rescaling is necessary to ensure the concentration $c$ remains between $0$ and $1$. But exactly why depends on matters not provided in the article. That is just one of many things it glosses over without explanation, including one of the parameters, $a$, which just appears without any reference at all.
